# Slim 3: how to access settings?

Tags: php, slim-3

Before the Slim 3 is released, codes below work fine:

settings.php,

```
return [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        'modules' => [
           'core' => 'config/core/modules.php',
           'local' => 'config/local/modules.php'
        ],
    ],
];
```

index.php

```
// Instantiate the app
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../src/settings.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);

$MyClass = new MyClass($app);
```

MyClass.php

```
class MyClass
{
    private $app;

    public function __construct($app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $local = require $app->settings['modules']['local'];
    }
```

But after the release, I get this error below:

> Notice: Undefined property: Slim\App::$settings in /...

So I can't use `$app->settings` anymore? What should I use then?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get settings like this:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();
$settings = $container->get('settings');
```

Comment: I had to include "global $app;" before these lines for this to work for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can  access settings route callables via $this

```
$modulesSettings = $this->get('settings')['modules']['local'];
```

For more information [read here](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/application.html)

Answer (score 3):

The address of the SLIM 3 configuration file is pro/src/settings.php, 
and you can add additional settings; In any route you can access them like this:

```
var_dump($this->get('settings')['logger']);
```