# Setting/retrieving mode in Slim Framework V3

Tags: php, configuration, slim, slim-3

I am new to Slim Framework (PHP). I was going through tutorials and testing some code and tried the following:

```
$app=new App([
    'mode'=>file_get_contents(INC_ROOT . '/mode.php')
]);
echo $app->config('mode');
```

The output was blank.

It seems the function `config()` works with V2, however I am using V3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slim 3: how to access settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281244/slim-3-how-to-access-settings)

Answer (score 3):

Slim 3 no longer has a `config` method.  Instead, you must [add configuration settings through the dependency injection container](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/application.html#application-configuration):

```
$app = new \Slim\App([
    'settings' => [
        'mode' => true
    ]
]);

$container = $app->getContainer();
echo $container->get('settings')['mode'];
```

### A few things worth noting:

Slim 3 no longer handles managing different versions of configuration settings through a `mode` setting.  So, you can set a value for a setting variable called `mode` as I've demonstrated here, but it won't actually do anything (i.e., Slim won't use it to determine your environment).

As an alternative, you can check out [userfrosting/Config](https://github.com/userfrosting/config), a library we've been working on that can search multiple directories and different environment configuration files, merging together their contents:

**/path/to/config/default.php**

```
return [
    'contacts' => [
        'housekeeper' => [
            'name' => 'Alex',
            'email' => 'alex@cleansthetoilet.com'
        ]
    ]
];
```

**/path/to/config/production.php**

```
return [
    'contacts' => [
        'housekeeper' => [
            'email' => 'alex@istheboss.com'
        ]
    ],
    'database' => [
        'password' => 'sup3rC-cr3t'
    ]
];
```

**index.php**

```
$app = new \Slim\App();

$container = $app->getContainer();    

// Site config object (separate from Slim settings)
$container['config'] = function ($c) {
    // Create and inject new config item
    $config = new \UserFrosting\Config\Config();

    $config->setPaths([
        '/path/to/config'
    ]);

    $config->loadConfigurationFiles('production');

    return $config;
};
```

This will recursively merge in the settings from `development.php` with those in `default.php`, updating settings with the same name and scope as necessary:

Running `print_r($container['config']);` returns:

```
[
    'contacts' => [
        'housekeeper' => [
            'name' => 'Alex',
            'email' => 'alex@istheboss.com'
        ]
    ],
    'database' => [
        'password' => 'sup3rC-cr3t'
    ]
]
```

Notice that the value of `contacts.housekeeper.email` has been updated to `'alex@istheboss.com'`, and that the `database` config info has been merged in.  Incidentally, you can also access config settings using the more convenient "dot syntax":

```
$config = $container->get('config');
echo $config['contacts.housekeeper.email'];
// Easier to type instead of $config['contacts']['housekeeper']['email'];
```

We recommend injecting this as a separate `config` service in Slim, rather than using their `settings` array.

You can combine this with [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) to load settings from your system environment, or any `.env` files you create:

**/path/to/config/production.php**

```
return [
    'database' => [
        'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
    ]
];
```